# How to create a new object when looping though a list of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string array like below

```
'[{"Bangalore": ["blr", "Bengaluru", "bangalore", "BANGALORE", "Bangalore"]}, {"delhi": ["del", "new delhi", "delhi", "nd", "dilli"]}]'
```

Now I want to loop throug each object and create a new object of my own and store it in a list

This is what I do

```
json_data = JSON.parse('[{"Bangalore": ["blr", "Bengaluru", "bangalore", "BANGALORE", "Bangalore"]}, {"delhi": ["del", "new delhi", "delhi", "nd", "dilli"]}]')   

tuples_to_return = []
for(i=0;i<json_data.length;i++) {
    for(key in json_data[i]) {
        //console.log(key, json_data[i][key])
        tuples_to_return.push({key: json_data[i][key].join()})
    }
}

console.log(tuples_to_return)
```

But the weird part is the output comes as

```
[ { key: 'blr,Bengaluru,bangalore,BANGALORE,Bangalore' },
  { key: 'del,new delhi,delhi,nd,dilli' } ]
```

Why is the key being printed as the string itself? I was expecting an output like

```
[ { "Bangalore": 'blr,Bengaluru,bangalore,BANGALORE,Bangalore' },
      { "delhi": 'del,new delhi,delhi,nd,dilli' } ]
```

When I do a console.log() of the key something like

```
for(i=0;i<json_data.length;i++) {
        for(key in json_data[i]) {
            console.log(key)
        }
    }
```

Then it gives me back the key values

```
Bangalore
delhi
```

Then what happens when I try to make an object and insert my keys there?

Comment: @gilbert-v — Like what they are doing on line 1 of their code?

Comment: You should not make Array top level in JSON to prevent hijacking: https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

Lead with an Object containing that array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
json_data = JSON.parse('[{"Bangalore": ["blr", "Bengaluru", "bangalore", "BANGALORE", "Bangalore"]}, {"delhi": ["del", "new delhi", "delhi", "nd", "dilli"]}]')   

tuples_to_return = []
for(i=0;i<json_data.length;i++) {
    for(key in json_data[i]) {
        //console.log(key, json_data[i][key])
        tuples_to_return.push({[key]: json_data[i][key].join()})
    }
}

console.log(tuples_to_return)
```

if you set `{key:'foo'}` you get a property name of key. If you set `{[key]:'foo'}` you get a property name of whatever string key contains.

The response I get from the above code is:

```
[
  {"Bangalore":"blr,Bengaluru,bangalore,BANGALORE,Bangalore"},
  {"delhi":"del,new delhi,delhi,nd,dilli"}
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate!